# App randomly crashing, MainActivity session error occurs

Tags: java, android, android-studio

sometimes the application does run but its very slow and messes up. I attached the main activity and the manifest, I think it is one of those that is making the application mess up. Sometimes it gives me this error : Session 'MainActivity': error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Main Activity

```
import Graphics.MyGLSurfaceView;
import gameInfo.GameDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //Runs before the application is created
    private Button mCampaignButton;
    private Context context = this;
    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    //When the application is created
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //New thread to perform database creation / filling
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            //Instantiate a GameDatabase object (this activity)
            final GameDatabase gDB = new GameDatabase(context);

            gDB.fillGameDatabase();
        }
    };

    Thread myThread = new Thread(runnable);
    myThread.start();

    mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLView);

    //Keeps screen on so it doesn't fall asleep
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    //Finding button by button id after application is created
    mCampaignButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.campaignButtonID);

    //Checks if the campaign button is clicked
    mCampaignButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Intent to go from main activity to campaign Level Select Activity
            final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CampaignSelectLevel.class);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    }

    }
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="tekvision.codedecrypter">
<!-- Tell the system this app requires OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".CampaignSelectLevel"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_campaign_select_level" >
    </activity>

    <!-- Anagrams.Modern Era is to get java class from different package-->
    <activity android:name="anagrams.Modern_Era"
              android:label="Modern_Era">

    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are declaring all the permissions in manifest file required by your application i.e.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

for more details check this: [uses-permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)

Comment: My last application did not need this, why does this one need it?

Comment: Ya that permission does not change anything

Comment: If you are storing data to SQLite or Sharedpreferences, accessing Internet and some other resources for that you need to declare permissions. Here you are using some other class "GameDatabase" and may be you are accessing some of the resources.

Comment: My game database is all hard coded for the information for each row. For example:  values.put(KEY_STATEMENT, "FIFA World Cup");
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, "BRAZIL");
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, "R.drawable.fifa_brazil.jpg");